# Derivative of a fraction - why can remove $y$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Reading http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/differentiation/fractional.html following is given :

$$ \frac {dy} {dx} = \frac {2x} {3y^2} $$
$$ = \frac {2x} {3x^{4/3}} $$

How is $ \frac {2x} {3x^{4/3}} $ arrived at ?

Why can we just remove $y$ and represent entire equation in terms of $x$ ?

Answer (score 2):

They start from $\color{blue}{y=x^{2/3}}$, this is simply plugged into:
$$\frac{2x}{3\color{blue}{y}^2} = \frac{2x}{3\left(\color{blue}{x^{2/3}}\right)^2}= \frac{2x}{3x^{4/3}}$$